# Passing values from one html to another html without extra script

Tags: html

I have a registration form such as below:

```
<form action="res.html" method="get">
    FirstName :<input type="text" name="first" /><br />
    LastName :<input type="text" name="last" /><br />
    Gender :<input type="radio" name="gender"  />Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" />Female<br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />   
</form>
```

I want to display the firstname & lastname in res.html file. I know I can use javascript, php or jsp, but without all of that script's help can we pass the values to res.html.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass data to file have extension is .html you should change file name res.html to res.php

Comment: Thanks. I came to know that I cant pass data without the help of other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass data between two pages without using php, or javascript. Notice that html is a markup language; which mean it does not give you the ability to store data into varibles, or pass it to a functions.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to use javascript or PHP.

if you use PHP, change the action file name extension to .php and then code there or if you use javascript, you can use ajax to send the data to another page(which is of course a .php page) and then get data from that page. Hope this helps !!

Comment: Thank you @Bilal Zafar. I know its such a rookie question, but you took your time to answer it.